# MySQL fulltext seacrh with PDO doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search

UPDATE:

Sorry everyone, it seems that I'm quite tired :) I just missed execute() part :)

---

I'm bumped into some problem.
Please look at code bellow.

```
$searchTerm = 'chr*';

$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user
    WHERE MATCH (user_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$statement = self::$replicaDB->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(1, $searchTerm);
$db_data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This query returns empty list (no errors, no exception)

But if I place search term in query directly then everything is working fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user
    WHERE MATCH (user_name) AGAINST ('chr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$statement = self::$replicaDB->query($sql);
$db_data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry everyone, it seems that I'm quite tired :) I just missed execute() part :)

Comment: You can answer your own question in case anyone has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks for hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, it seems that I'm quite tired :) I just missed execute() part :)

The code should be:

```
$searchTerm = 'chr*';

$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user
WHERE MATCH (user_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$statement = self::$replicaDB->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(1, $searchTerm);
$statement->execute();
$db_data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```